# UserControl ItemsControl Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, itemscontrol

I am developing a UserControl which contains an ItemsControl of TextBoxes. I have a caption class which is used to control the location/Text of the TextBlock

In the Window XAML

```
<local:UserControl1>
    <local:UserControl1.Captions>
        <local:Caption Foreground="Black" Size="10"  Text="{Binding Path=SomeText}" X="100" Y ="100"></local:Caption>
    </local:UserControl1.Captions>
</local:UserControl1>
```

The ItemsControl is a canvas with the dataTemplate being a TextBox

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Captions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Beige" Width="{Binding Path=Width}" Height="{Binding Path=Height}"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground}" FontSize="{Binding Path=Size}" ></TextBlock>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y,PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X,PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the UserControl is an ObservableCollection of "Caption" which is derived from Framework element

```
public class Caption :FrameworkElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The actual text to display
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The font size
    /// </summary>
    public int Size
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SizeProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The text foreground color
    /// </summary>
    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Top location of the text
    /// </summary>
    public double Y
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(YProperty); }
        set { SetValue(YProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The left location of the text
    /// </summary>
    public double X
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(XProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Caption:{0}//{1}.{2}", this.X, this.Y, this.Text);
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string),
                                                                                          typeof(Caption),
                                                                                          new PropertyMetadata(
                                                                                              OnPropertyChanged));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty SizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Size", typeof(int),
                                                                                          typeof(Caption),
                                                                                          new PropertyMetadata(
                                                                                              OnPropertyChanged));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Foreground",
                                                                                                typeof(Brush),
                                                                                                typeof(Caption),
                                                                                                new PropertyMetadata
                                                                                                    (OnPropertyChanged));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Y", typeof(double),
                                                                                       typeof(Caption),
                                                                                       new PropertyMetadata(
                                                                                           OnPropertyChanged));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("X", typeof(double),
                                                                                       typeof(Caption),
                                                                                       new PropertyMetadata(
                                                                                           OnPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var caption = (Caption)d;
    }
}
```

Each time a Caption is added to the collection it is added to the logical tree

```
void Captions_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        foreach(Caption c in e.NewItems)
        {
            AddLogicalChild(c);
            c.DataContext = this.DataContext;

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the binding for the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` are not working

The debug produces the following

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 54 : Created BindingExpression
>   (hash=14626603) for Binding (hash=8360729)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 :   Path: 'X'
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603):
>   Default mode resolved to OneWay
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 59 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603):
>   Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603):
>   Attach to WpfApplicationQuery.Caption.Left (hash=33822626)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603):
>   Resolving source
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 68 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603):
>   Found data context element: Caption (hash=33822626) (OK)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603):
>   Activate with root item
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603): 
>   Item at level 0 is null - no accessor
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603):
>   TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 86 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603):
>   TransferValue - using fallback/default value 'NaN'
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 87 : BindingExpression (hash=14626603):
>   TransferValue - using final value 'NaN'
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector
>   are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type;
>   Type='Caption'

So it seems to binding incorrectly, and I don't know what the last error means

Also, previously, I had Caption derived from DependencyObject, and everything worked (.i.e things got displayed), except Databinding. Hence  the switch to framworkElement, as described somewhere on stackoverflow ( and a blog post which I now can't find)

**Edit 2012-02-14**
Changed the first XAML sample code

**Edit 2012-02-14**
Caption derives from FrameworkElement so that it can participate in databinding as described here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/aff23943-5483-40b2-816b-4ce687bc6bf8/
and here
http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008_10_01_archive.html

If Caption implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
<local:UserControl1>
    <local:UserControl1.Captions>
        <local:Caption Foreground="Black" Size="10"  Text="Hello" X="100" Y ="100"></local:Caption>
        <local:Caption Foreground="Black" Size="10"  Text="{Binding Path=Title}" X="100" Y ="100"></local:Caption>
    </local:UserControl1.Captions>
</local:UserControl1>
```

The first line works. The second does'nt, this error is traced.

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element

However, if Caption is derived from FrameworkElement, it now provides it's own ItemTemplate
So the binding error relating to ItemTemplate/ Selector is produced.

Comment: It is definitely not a good idea to derive `Caption` from FrameworkElement, since Captions are plain data objects. Their view aspects are defined by ItemTemplate and ItemContainerStyle. Let `Caption` implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) to support data binding.

Comment: And don't manually add you data objects to the logical tree. This is done automatically by the ItemsControl whenever you the ItemSource changes.

Comment: Caption did originally derive from INotifyPropertyChanged. However it can no longer do databing. This binding error is generated "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element." as per this blog post

http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008_10_01_archive.html

Comment: I can see no reason why it shouldn't work to bind an ItemControl's `ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection<Caption>`, when `Caption` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This is the absolute standard scenario for binding to collections. The binding error you noticed must have a different cause.

Comment: I have to say the same as Phil did in his answer: it worked fine for me with your ItemsControl definition, with only an `ObservableCollection<Caption> Captions` property in a plain class (instead of ViewModelBase) used as DataContext.

Comment: Yes, it does work if the MainViewModel is the datacontext for the MainWindow, for example. I will re-do the question to make it more clear what I am doing

Comment: It does'nt work however if 'ObservableCollection<Caption> Captions' is a dependency property of a usercontrol

Comment: Why do you have a UserControl as the DataContext of an ItemsControls? That sounds rather strange to me.

Comment: The ItemsControl is within the UserControl. The ItemsControl binds to a dependency property "Captions" which is also in the UserControl. Subsequenly, in a window, the UserControl is hosted and the UserControl.Captions property is bound to something, probably a viewmodel

Comment: Then the DataContext of the ItemsControl is identical to the DataContext of the containing UserControl. It is not the UserControl itself! And it still works for me, i tried it.

Comment: When you used your UserControl in a window what did it look like?

Comment: The same as if I directly put the ItemsControl in a Window, since the UserControl only contains the ItemsControl, nothing more.

Comment: Just had another look at your question. Of course, when you directly set the Captions collection in XAML **there is no binding** and hence no DataContext. Then the binding inside your UserControl also has no DataContext. When you write `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Captions}"` this **does not** bind to the Captions property in the UserControl, but binds to a Captions property on the DataContext.

Comment: It seems like you are having problems with a dependency property on your user control of type Collection. These can be tricky at times, have a look at that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx .Besides that, try passing a in code filled collection to your usercontrol and check if that works.

Comment: @dowhilefor Your summary is correct, and link was useful